# Vue3 v-if do not see changes of the variable in condition

Tags: if-statement, vuejs3, reactive

```
<template>
    <EditStudentModal v-if="showModal==='show'"/>
    <div v-for="student in prop.students" :key="student.id">
        <StudentItem
            :student="student"
            @editStudent="openEditModal"
        />
    </div>
</template>
```

part of my

```
let showModal = ref('');

const openEditModal = (data) => {
    showModal = 'show';
}
```

the value of showModal variable changes after triggering the @editStudent event, but v-if does not see it

Comment: i changed showModal = 'show' to showModal.value = 'show'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
showModal = 'show'
```

to

```
showModal.value = 'show'
```